# Sorting an array by number inside string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
var arr = [ '4msterdam', 'Par1s', 'N3w York', '2urich'];
```

How can I sort the array by the number that's contained in each element of the array?

Comment: What kind of strange application needs this?

Comment: Łukasz, would you like to accept my answer/ upvote it?

Answer (score 1):

A good approach would be using `Array#sort` and `RegExp` for array sorting, based on the first matched digit in every element.

```js
var arr = ['4msterdam', 'Par1s', 'N3w York', '2urich'];
    sorted = arr.sort((a,b) => a.match(/\d/)[0] - b.match(/\d/)[0]);
    
    console.log(sorted);
```